# How to send AuthPayload to Firebase Realtime-Database through HTTP Post request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I had built my app to send data to Firebase RealtimeDB with http.post requests, and everything was working perfectly until I added read & write rules, which are not very complex btw:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read"  : false,
    ".write" : false,

    "client":{
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code for the request is the following:

```
createClient (ClientModel client) async{

    final userData = new SavedUserData();

    final url = '$_dbUrl/cliente/${userData.uid}.json?auth=${userData.uid}';

    final resp = await http.post(url, body: clientModelToJson(client));
```

I get a parse error, and I get it, auth is not sending a .json file, but neither:

- auth={"uid":"myUsersUid"}
- auth="{"uid":"myUsersUid"}"
- Encoding a Map with {"uid":"myUsersUid"} and appending it to the url

seem to do the trick!

I'm mostly certain that I'm making a massive rookie mistake, but I dont seem to be able to see where. Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to send an arbitrary UID to the Realtime Database REST API.  That would actually be a pretty big security hole - it would allow anyone with an internet connection to impersonate registered user knowing only their UID.

In order to understand how auth works with RTDB, start with the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).  You have two options for passing an auth token:

> Authenticate users through one of the following methods:
>
> - Google OAuth2 access tokens - Typically, the ability to read from and write to the Realtime Database is governed by Realtime Database
>   Rules. But, you can access your data from a server and grant that
>   server full read and write access to your data with a Google OAuth2
>   access token generated from a service account.
> - Firebase ID tokens - You might also want to send requests authenticated as an individual user, like limiting access with
>   Realtime Database Rules on the client SDKs. The REST API accepts the
>   same Firebase ID tokens used by the client SDKs.

You will need to pass an ID token (not a UID), which can only be obtained through a successful sign-in by the end user account.  You can learn more about ID tokens [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions).

Comment: I got it all wrong the first time I read that documentation, thanks for your time!